# How to import multiple jpeg images in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I'm trying to import multiple black and white images from a folder into R. There is no pattern to the name of each file.

I have tried a couple different approaches:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:\\images", pattern=".jpeg",all.files=T, full.names=F, no.. = T)
```

and

```
x = readImage(system.file(images, *.png, package=EBImage))
```

with no luck.

Ultimately I would like to import these images and create a matrix with each row representing an image and each column representing a pixel number, ranging from pixel 0 to pixel 783 (these are 28x28 images so 786 total pixels).

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the images in a list I would use `lapply`:

```
list_of_images = lapply(files, readImage)
```

And convert it to a matrix:

```
image_matrix = do.call('cbind', lapply(list_of_images, as.numeric))
```